# Adding buttons to table rows in a loop generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a loop generated table that fills its rows using an object array retrieved from a database query.

This is the coda that generates the table

```
indices = ["razonSocial", "nombre1", "telefonoFijo1", "telefonoMovil1", "correoElectronico1", "clave"];
indiceBotones = ["id"];
var selectArray = [];
jQuery.each(returned.listaproveedorfamilia, function(i, val) {                   
    selectArray.push({
        "id": val.id,
        "razonSocial": val.razonSocial, 
        "nombre1": val.nombre1,
        "telefonoFijo1": val.telefonoFijo1,
        "telefonoMovil1": val.telefonoMovil1,
        "correoElectronico1": val.correoElectronico1,
        "clave": val.clave
    });
});

$.each(selectArray, function(i, selected) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $.each(indices, function(i, indice) {
        $('<td>').html(selected[indice]).appendTo(tr);
    });
    $.each(indiceBotones, function(i, indiceBoton){
        //Here I need to add the code for the two buttons in the same cell
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```

This is how the table looks
[image: This is how the table looks]

And I want it to have buttons like this in the last column

[image: Table with buttons]

This is an example of the code generated by the loop for every row

```
<tr>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>PCR</td>
</tr>
```

After the last td, and additional td should be added containing the following tags

```
<td>
    <a title="Editar" href="<?php echo site_url('proveedor/edit/' HERE GOES THE VALUE OF THE ID selected[indiceBoton]); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a> 
    <a title="Eliminar" href="<?php echo site_url('proveedor/remove/'HERE GOES THE VALUE OF THE ID selected[indiceBoton]); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
</td>
```

So for every row, the following code shoud be created

```
<tr>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>00020</td>
    <td>PCR</td>
    <td>
        <a title="Editar" href="<?php echo site_url('proveedor/edit/' HERE GOES THE VALUE OF THE ID selected[indiceBoton]); ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></a> 
        <a title="Eliminar" href="<?php echo site_url('proveedor/remove/'HERE GOES THE VALUE OF THE ID selected[indiceBoton]); ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How could I modify the loop to generate these tags?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you don't need the loop for the buttons. It seems you just need to add the two `<td><button></button></td>` after the inner `$.each` loop that is fetching **indices**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Dynamic URLs**

Since your URLs are going to be generated with JS, you need to let it know what your site URL is. You could hardcode it in your JS, or make it dynamic, so that it does not break if you switch domains. To do this, you can add this as the first `<script>` tag in your PHP page's `<head>` section:

```
<script>window.SITE_ROOT = "<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>";</script>
```

It will create a global variable that your JS can then access.

**2. Adding the buttons**

Then, you can use this variable in your code:

```
$.each(indiceBotones, function(i, indiceBoton){
    $('<td>').html(
                     '<a title="Editar" href="' + SITE_ROOT + 'proveedor/edit/' + selected[indiceBoton] + '">Edit</a> ' 
                   + '<a title="Eliminar" href="' + SITE_ROOT + 'proveedor/remove/' + selected[indiceBoton] + '">Remove</a>'
                  ).appendTo(tr);
});
```

**3. Demo**

Check out the below demo to see how everything should work:

```js
// For the demo
var returned = {listaproveedorfamilia:[{id:1,name:"John"},{id:2,name:"Jessica"},{id:3,name:"Peter"},{id:4,name:"Harry"},{id:5,name:"Celia"}]},
    tbody = $('table tbody');

// Nothing changed here, I just simplified the data structure for the demo
indices = ["name"];
indiceBotones = ["id"];
var selectArray = [];
jQuery.each(returned.listaproveedorfamilia, function(i, val) {                   
    selectArray.push({
        "id": val.id,
        "name": val.name
    });
});

$.each(selectArray, function(i, selected) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $.each(indices, function(i, indice) {
        $('<td>').html(selected[indice]).appendTo(tr);
    });
    
    // Here, we use the SITE_ROOT variable to create the links
    $.each(indiceBotones, function(i, indiceBoton){
        $('<td>').html(
          '<a title="Editar" href="' + SITE_ROOT + 'proveedor/edit/' + selected[indiceBoton] + '">Edit</a> ' 
        + '<a title="Eliminar" href="' + SITE_ROOT + 'proveedor/remove/' + selected[indiceBoton] + '">Remove</a>'
        ).appendTo(tr);
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- The following line should be the first script loaded in the <head> section.
     It will allow your JS script to know what the site root is.
     This is the output of "echo site_url('/')": -->
<script>window.SITE_ROOT = "http://yoursite.com/";</script>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Options</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the same logic as you have for the other table cells. I don't believe `<?php echo site_url() ?>` would resolve to site url when being executed in javascript. Instead, the easiest workaround would be to hard-code starting url path

```
...
$.each(selectArray, function(i, selected) {
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    $.each(indices, function(i, indice) {
        $('<td>').html(selected[indice]).appendTo(tr);
    });
    $.each(indiceBotones, function(i, indiceBoton){
        var itemId = selected[indiceBoton];

        var editButtonUrl = "/proveedor/edit/" + itemId;

        var editButtonHtml = "<a title='Editar' href='" + editButtonUrl + "' class='btn btn-info btn-xs'><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span></a>";

        var deleteButtonUrl = "proveedor/remove/" + itemId;

        var deleteButtonHtml = "<a title='Eliminar' href='" + deleteButtonUrl + "' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'><span class='fa fa-trash'></span></a>";

        $('<td>').html(editButtonHtml + deleteButtonHtml).appendTo(tr);
    });
    tbody.append(tr);
});
```